# How to find name of key for use in ~/.XCompose? (specifically keypad plus and minus)

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, input-method, compose-key

I use [XIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Input_Method) under Debian Linux with Gnome 2. Many compose sequences are already defined in the system, including the one for `±` sign:

```
palec@Palec:~$ grep PLUS-MINUS /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
<Multi_key> <plus> <minus>          : "±"   plusminus # PLUS-MINUS SIGN
```

This does not work with numpad of my Lenovo G550’s keyboard.

I noticed that numbers on numpad require `KP_` prefix to be matched, so I tried adding copy of the original rule with keys changed to `KP_plus` and `KP_minus` to my `~/.XCompose`, where I already have other rules I use in addition to those from the system `Compose` file. No luck though.

I did not manage to find any useful doc for XIM nor `~/.XCompose`. Is there any? Most of information on XIM and compose sequences I got from forums I found by googling. How to get the name of a key for use in `~/.XCompose`? Particularly, what are they for numpad <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>?

I do not insist on XIM, but I want to be able to configure custom compose sequences. If there is another, preferably better documented solution, I’d like to hear about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. How to get the name of a key: Use the command `xev` and press the keys of interest. The name is shown as last word in the parenthesis in the terminal output.
2. Particularly, what are the names for numpad <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>−</kbd>: `xev` tells me, that they are `KP_Add` and `KP_Subtract`.